# Combining multiple click functions into one function

Tags: jquery, html, css, json

I have 9 click handle functions that are almost identical, the only things that are changing is the ID number of the button being clicked which has a different index number. And its corresponding content with a ID and unique index number.

When a button with the ID="but0" is clicked, the content with a ID="cont0" is then displayed via css display:none;/display:block;. There are 3 of these functions in the code snippets below, but eventually will have 9... But I know there is a way to easily combine the functions into one.

I have attached some snippets for you to looks at.

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET', 
    url: 'data.json', 
    data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        
        $.each(data, function(i) {
            var link = $('.more-link');

            var cont = "<div class='content' id ='cont" + i  + "'>" + data[i].content + "</div>";
            
            var back = "<a class='back' href='http://localhost:8888/postPopulate/Feb22.9.53AM/'>BACK</a>";
            
            var thumb = "<img class='thumb' src=" + data[i].thumbnail + ">";
            
            var title = "<h1 class='title'>" + data[i].title + "</h1>";
            
            var exc = "<p class='excerpt'>" + data[i].excerpt + "</p>";
            
            var click = "<a class='click' href='" + data[i].permalink + "'" + " id ='" + "but" + i  + "'>" + "Read More</a>";
            
            $('.content-thumb').append(title);
            $('.content-thumb').append(thumb);
            $('.content-thumb').append(exc);
            $('.content-thumb').append(click);
            
            $('body').append(cont);
            
            $('#but0').click(function(){
                $('#cont0').css('display', 'block');
                $('.content').append(back);
                $('.content-thumb').css('display','none');
            });
            
            $('#but1').click(function(){
                $('#cont1').css('display', 'block');
                $('.content').append(back);
                $('.content-thumb').css('display','none');
            });
            
            $('#but2').click(function(){
                $('#cont2').css('display', 'block');
                $('.content').append(back);
                $('.content-thumb').css('display','none');
            });
                

        });//END OF FOR LOOP
        
        $.each(data, function(i){
            
        var link = $('.click');
        var perma = JSON.stringify(data[i].permalink);
//        var pArray = [i];
            
                perma = JSON.parse(perma);
                perma = perma.replace("http://www.capetownetc.com/blog/", "");
                perma = perma.replace("http://www.capetownetc.com/events/", "");
                perma = perma.replace("http://www.capetownetc.com/mykitchen/", "");

//            pArray.push(perma);
            
            $(link).attr("href", "http://localhost:8888/postPopulate/Feb22.9.53AM/#");
            
            });
    }//END OF SUCCESS FUNC
});//END OF AJAX

//SNIPPETS

//console.log(element.id);


//var link = ('.more-link');
//var title = "<h1 class='title'>" + data[0].title + "</h1>";
//            var thumb = "<img class='thumb' src=" + data[0].thumbnail + ">";
//var exc = "<p class='excerpt'>" + data[0].excerpt + "</p>";            
//            $('.thumbnail').click(function(){
//                $('body').html(title);
//                $('body').append(thumb);
//                $('body').append(exc);
//                $(link).attr("href", "http://localhost:8888/Practice1/Task1-Feb17/#");
//            });


//var cont = "<div class='content'>" + data[4].content + "</div>";
//            
//            $('body').html(cont);
```

```css
.content-wrap {
 display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.title{
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #398d46;
}

strong{
    display: block;
}

.content{
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #333;
}

.thumb{
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    height: auto;
}

.excerpt{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    text-align: justify;
}

.back{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: darkred;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 10px;
}

.more-link{
    display: none;
}

.content {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Rugby Thumbnails</title>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
    
<body>
    <div class="content-thumb">
    
    </div>

     <script src="js/main2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/arrayTest.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Plenty of ways to do this given by the answers below, just make sure you're passing the ID of the clicked button into the function so you can handle it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a data attribute to your buttons

```
<a class='click' href='...' id='...' data-id=' id '>" + "Read More</a>"
```

then implement the click with

```
$('.click').click(function(){
    var index = $(this).data("id");
    $('#cont' + index).css('display', 'block');
    // other things to execute
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Your solution has worked. I appreciate it :D

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    // .. Do something according to the id you get.
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I up voted your comment but I do not have enough reputation for it to register.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#but0, #but1, #but2').on('click', some_function);
```

Try the above code with your functions replaced. This should do your job that you are looking for. 
**NOTE : Make sure you have spaces between the "," and "#" for every IDs.**

Comment: Thank you for your help. I up voted your comment but I do not have enough reputation for it to register.